# Kick off all the jobs at a time in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have 15 jobs in Jenkins and i need to kick off all the jobs at a time.

Currently the jobs are kicked off one by one and i need all the jobs should be kicked of simultaneously by the scheduler. 
Kindly help me this

Comment: Suresh, maybe you could show some of what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

[Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) Plugin will help you.